# How to show applying gradient descent on a differentiable convex function generates a non-increasing sequence?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable convex function, i.e., $f(y)\geq f(x)+\langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle\,\,\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We do not assume that the gradient is Lipschitz continuous. Is it possible to show that the sequence of the function values $\{f(x^{k})\}_{k\geq0}$ non-increasing where $x^{k+1}=x^k -\alpha \nabla f(x^k)$ and $\alpha>0$ ($\alpha$ can be selected so that it does not create a problem)?

Comment: Doesn't this follow from plugging in $y=x^{k+1}$, $x=x^k$ in your defining property of convex function?

Comment: @Jose27: No. If you plug them in you get $f(x^{k+1})\geq f(x^k)-\alpha||\nabla f(x^k)||$. We need $f(x^{k+1}) -f(x^k)\leq 0$ which is not implied by your suggestion.

Comment: Right! I flipped a minus sign for some reason. I think the answer will depend on $\alpha$, since the conclusion is not true if $f(x)=|x|^2$ and $\alpha>1$.

Comment: @ Jose27: We can select a small $\alpha$ to avoid cases like that.

Comment: Can $\alpha$ depend on $k$ or should it be fixed throughout the iteration?

Comment: @gerw: fix one is of more interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work if $\nabla f$ is not Lipschitz and $\alpha > 0$ is fixed. Let us take
$$
f(x) = |x|^{3/2} \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb R.$$
Then, if $x_k > 0$ is small enough (depending on $\alpha$), we have
$$
\alpha \nabla f(x_k) > 2 x_k,$$
i.e., $|x_{k+1}| > |x_k|$ and, thus, $f(x_{k+1}) > f(x_k)$.

Comment: Suggested edit: $f(x)=|x|^{\frac32}$. Your function is not bounded below and $|x_{k+1}|>|x_k|$ does not mean $f(x_{k+1})>f(x_k)$.

Comment: @foxell: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @gerw: how did you get $\alpha \nabla f(x_k) > 2 x_k,$? Can you please complete the steps? Also, can you think of any other conditions than Lipschitzness of the gradient that provides a monotonically decreasing sequence? I want to know if Lipschitzness of the gradient is the only way to generate a monotonically decreasing sequence of function values?

Comment: @Sepide: Just compute $\nabla f$. Without Lipschitz gradient: Maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06461v1 is interesting?

Comment: @gerw: Thank your for the paper. I still cannot figure out how you get that inequality. $\nabla f(x_k)=\frac{3}{2}x_k^{\frac{1}{2}}$ so you get $x_{k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}} - x_{k}^{\frac{3}{2}} \geq  \frac{3}{2} x_k^{\frac{1}{2}}(x_{k+1}-x_k)$. Then, $x_{k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}}  \geq  -\frac{3}{2} \alpha x_k + x_{k}^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

Comment: You just use that $\nabla f(x_k)$ goes slower to zero than $x_k$, hence $\alpha \nabla f(x_k) > 2 x_k$, thus, $x_{k+1} < -x_k$.

Comment: @gerw: honestly, I cannot see what you are saying. Can you please use the inequality I have and show this algebraically? I am not following your intuition.

Comment: I do not use your inequality, I just plug in the values.

Comment: @gerw: I think it is better to say the following. When $0<x_k<1$, one can write $x_k^{\frac{1}{2}}> x_k$. Therefore, there exist an $\alpha>0$ such that $\frac{3}{2}\alpha>2$. This implies $\frac{3}{2}\alpha x_k^{\frac{1}{2}}> 2x_k$ so $\alpha \nabla f(x_k) > 2x_k$. Your reasoning does not work when $0<\alpha \leq \frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: It also works for small $\alpha$. As soon as $0 < x_k < (3 \alpha /4)^2$, you have $\alpha \nabla f(x_k)  = 3 \alpha \sqrt{x_k} /2 > 2 x_k$.

Comment: @gerw: so the takeaway is that for small $x_k$ and large $\alpha$ we may not be able to decrease the function value. That is why you asked me whether $\alpha$ can vary, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There are variants of the gradient descent method in which $\alpha$ is allowed to vary.